# Stone-Cech compactification and isolated points

Tags: general-topology

How to prove each point of X is an isolated point of BX and no other point of BX-X is an isolated point in BX??

Since closure of X is BX so there cannot exist any isolated point.
Am I correct?

I Cannot prove each isolated point of X is an isolated point of BX. Please help

Comment: How do you define $\beta X$? By what properties?

Comment: The latter point is correct, the former needs an argument of sorts.

Comment: BX is stone-cech compactification of X.

Comment: I know, but what properties are you allowed to use of $\beta X$?

Comment: i should use deness of X

Comment: Look at my answer. It uses denseness of $X$

Comment: now it is understood

Answer (score 2):

If $p$ is isolated in $X$ then $\{p\}$ and $X\setminus \{p\}$ are disjoint closed sets of $X$ and so they have disjoint closures in $\beta X$. As $\beta X$ is $T_1$, the former closure is still $\{p\}$ and $\beta X = \overline{X} = \{p\} \cup \overline{X\setminus \{p\}}$ (closures in $\beta X$) and so $\{p\}$ is also open in $\beta X$ as the complement of $\overline{X\setminus\{p\}}$.

Another argument: as $\{p\}$ is open in $X$, there is an open set $O$ of $\beta X$ such that $O\cap X=\{p\}$. This means that $O=\{p\}$ as otherwise $O \setminus \{p\}$ would be a non-empty open subset of $\beta X$ that misses the dense set $X$, which cannot be. 
This only uses the denseness of $X$ and $\beta X$ being $T_1$.

If $\{p\}$ were an isolated point point of $\beta X$ in with $p \notin X$, then $\{p\}$ is an open set of $\beta X$ missing the dense subset $X$, which cannot be.